# Strange MVP behavior during translation

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, glm-math, vertex-shader

I'm learning the basics of OpenGL and trying to translate a triangle with ortho projection. I don't see what I expect, what am I doing wrong?

My Vertex buffer:

```
Vertices[0] = Vector3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
Vertices[1] = Vector3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
Vertices[2] = Vector3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Vertices), Vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

Vertex shader:

```
#version 330

layout (location = 0) in vec3 Position;

uniform mat4 gMVP;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = gMVP * vec4(Position, 1.0);
}
```

MVP calculation and rendering:

```
    glm::mat4 p = glm::ortho(-2.0f, 2.0f, -2.0f, 2.0f, -2.0f, 2.0f);
    glm::mat4 v = glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(0,0,1), glm::vec3(0,0,0), glm::vec3(0,1,0)); 
    glm::mat4 m = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
    glm::mat4 MVP = p * v * m; 

    glUniformMatrix4fv(gMVPLocation, 1, GL_TRUE, &MVP[0][0]);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glutSwapBuffers();
```

the result:

[image]

Shouldn't it just move to the right along the X axis?

Comment: @Rabbid76 fixed, didn't help

Comment: `glUniformMatrix4fv(gMVPLocation, 1, GL_TRUE, &MVP[0][0]);` -> `glUniformMatrix4fv(gMVPLocation, 1, GL_FALSE, &MVP[0][0]);`. See [GLSL Programming/Vector and Matrix Operations](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GLSL_Programming/Vector_and_Matrix_Operations)

Answer (score 4):

The 3rd parameter of [`glUniformMatrix4fv`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glUniform.xhtml) causes that the matrix will be transposed when it is set to the uniform. [OpenGL Mathematics (GLM)](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.9/index.html) constructs the matrices in the same way, as GLSL constructs variables of type `mat4`.
The matrix has not to be transposed when it is set to the uniform:

<s>`glUniformMatrix4fv(gMVPLocation, 1, GL_TRUE, &MVP[0][0]);`</s>

```c
glUniformMatrix4fv(gMVPLocation, 1, GL_FALSE, &MVP[0][0]);
```

In GLSL the vector has to be multiplied to the matrix from the right. See [GLSL Programming/Vector and Matrix Operations](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GLSL_Programming/Vector_and_Matrix_Operations)